# create instance of Subclass in java

Tags: java

I have

```
class Class1{

  public class Employee{

  }
  public static void Main(String[] args){
      Class1 c = new Class1();
      // Create instance of Employee Class  
  }
}
```

How to create instance of class Employee?

Comment: Employee emp= new Class1().new Employee();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Objects that are instances of an inner class exist within an instance of the outer class. Consider the following classes:

```
class OuterClass {
    ...
    class InnerClass {
        ...
    }
}
```

> An instance of InnerClass can exist only within an instance of OuterClass and has direct access to the methods and fields of its enclosing instance.
>
> To instantiate an inner class, you must first instantiate the outer class. Then, create the inner object within the outer object with this syntax:

```
OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass();
```

ref :[Doc Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Answer (score 3):

```
class Class1 {

   public class Employee {

   }
   public static void Main(String[] args){
       Class1 c = new Class1();
       Employee e = c.new Employee();
       // Create instance of Employee Class  
   }
}
```

You do need the instance of the superclass to instanciate an Employee, because Employee is a non static Subclass of Class1.

Otherwise add the static keyword to Employee like this

```
public static class Employee {

}
```

to be able to instanciate an Employee without an instance of Class1, which would then look like this:

```
Employee e = new Class1.Employee();
```